# Wordpress theme showing blank page and wp-admin show PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress

I upload my site on GoDaddy and the site showed the blank page. All the configurations have been done properly.

The same site has been uploading on another hosting account where it is working fine.

URL that is not working: http://workshop.planvisionmn.com

The main page is just blank, when u try to access wp-admin it shows PHP code which never happened to me before.

Note: I tried to rename all the plugin`s to disable them and to check if they are the reason but the issue persisted.

Comment: Looks like maybe PHP isn't installed. Your PHP documents are being served as `text/plain`.

Comment: But there are other sub domains working fine on the same hosting account

Comment: My host allows me to select different PHP installations on different subdomains. In fact, each subdomain we have has completely different configuration.

Comment: I am using GoDaddy ...

Comment: I've never used GoDaddy, so that doesn't mean a lot to me.

Comment: Yes @David it started working. GoDaddy had some fault with the DNS